# Merge counter-words tag with counters

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

In chat, broccoli forest noticed that [counter-words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-words) and [counters](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counters) were duplicates:

1. [counter-words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-words):

   > 助数詞. Suffices attached to a number to use the number to count things, people, or events.
2. [counters](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counters):

   > 助数詞. Often called 'classifiers' in linguistics.

I can make one into a synonym of the other, but which one should it be?  I'm personally fond of the simple [counters](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counters).  We should probably rewrite the description, too.  (At a minimum, I can throw the two together and change *suffices* to *suffixes*.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm for merging (needless to say...). I originally thought that "counter words" is more misunderstanding-free than "counters" but obviously I'm not very good at grasping English nuances...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using "counters", for three reasons:

1. **It isn't redundant.** The "-words" part of the alternative is not necessary and is rather unhelpful. Counters are more specific than words, so I suggest we cut out the "word" part, which can be implied by the "counter" part, and keep the tag names as simple as possible.
2. **"Counter" is what most people know it as.** I suppose some people do use "counter word" in speech, but I think it's much more common to use plain "counter". I see questions like "what's the counter for chairs?" much more frequently than with the extra "word" after counter. Even though "counter-word" is understandable, I think it's best to keep it as what people use.
3. **Counters is plural rather than singular.** This might sound like a weird reason, and maybe I have a misunderstanding of the system. But whenever you type in a tag search field, it always finds a tag name containing the exact string you input, and *nothing less*. That means that if you type in singular "counter", both "counters" and "counter-words" will appear, but if you type in plural "counters", it will find only "counters", since the extra S doesn't appear in the other one. I'm not sure if this is really a big deal or not, but I thought I should point it out.

As for the description, I think we should, at the minimum, use the current counter-words description, and possibly append the counters description at the end of it. As it currently stands, the counters description on its own provides almost no information about counters.